# speed limits on highway

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-wego

I would like to do a project on speed limits on highways in germany. I want to know the distance between changes of the speed limit. To do this I need get a dataset which includes the speed limit traffic signs or the areas where a speed limit is set along ONE highway.
I havent worked with here yet. And before I dig into the details I would like to know if here is the right tool to do this project. And of course it would be nice if you could also tell me briefly how to do it, since I dont't even know where to start in here :)

Thanks a lot!

I tried Openstreetmaps before, but the data is too outdated. For example you cannot see speed limits due to construction works.

I found this link on other posts https://github.com/seaBass3/here-pde-speed-limit
but it seems not valid any more

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by different approaches, but one the most feasible, is the following:

By using the tool HereTraffic API v7 you can get real-time traffic flow and information about traffic signs, by using query parameters, response structures, and data types.

You can get all the information required on real-time traffic flow data in JSON, including information on speed and jam factor for the region(s) defined in each request. Can also deliver additional data such as the geometry of the road segments in relation to the flow.

Provides aggregated information about traffic incidents in JSON, including the type and location of each traffic incident, status, start and end time, and other relevant data. This data is useful to dynamically optimize route calculations.

And if you need historical information also like from past dates you can always use Here Probe Data to get the data which can be compared with different datasets.

This is one of the examples you can use in order to get all the information you need:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow?locationReferencing=shape&in=bbox:13.400,52.500,13.405,52.505"